# Can I upgrade Laravel from version 5.0 directly to 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a site built in Laravel 5.0 and would like to upgrade to Laravel 5.2

Do I have to first upgrade to 5.1 and then upgrade to 5.2 or is it possible to upgrade directly from 5.0 to 5.2

The only guides I can find at the moment don't seem to offer the option from 5.0 to 5.2 so I was wondering if there are too many changes to jump from 5.0 directly to 5.2.

Comment: i think most of the 5.1 and 5.2 changes are not related, you will need to follow both upgrade guides laravel provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the migrations between releases is a manual migration, you may follow the instruction for every single migration in chronological order and then run the `composer update` only once.

Nevertheless, I think the optimal approach is to migrate to the next version, verify everything works, and repeat until you get to the last release.